# array[byte] to HBITMAP or CBitmap

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an array of bytes (which I read through a stream directly from a .bmp and then store as a BLOB in a database) which I want to display as icons in a CImageList. Therefore I want to somehow load my data into an HBITMAP or CBitmap. I have done it like this up to now, reading from a file:

```
hPic = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, strPath, IMAGE_BITMAP, dwWidth, dwHeight, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_VGACOLOR);
...
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(hPicRet);
```

But obviously, that only works for files, but not for byte-arrays. How can I get the same result, but reading from an array of byte?

**Edit:**
Note that my array does not contain just the colour information, but rather the complete file as it is written on disk, including all headers and meta-data. It seems to me that discarding all that information is a bad idea.

Comment: Related: (opposite direction) [Gdiplus::Bitmap to BYTE array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340017/gdiplusbitmap-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you have the information loaded into a BYTE array named bytes....

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh;
bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)bytes;

BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih;
bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(bytes + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
BITMAPINFO* bmi;
bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;

void* bits;
bits = (void*)(bytes + bmfh->bfOffBits);

HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS) ;

::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

It's a little messy and could use a hefty dose of error checking, but the basic idea is sound.

Comment: Worked out of the box! Thank you! Could I ask what kinds of error checks you would suggest?

Comment: @kdansky Verify that bmi, bmih, and bits are all within the bytes array. Verify that GetDC succeeded. Verify that CreateDIBitmap succeeded. You might also consider swapping GetDC(NULL) with a more appropriate call to get a DC. GetDC(NULL) uses the DC of the entire screen to figure out an appropriate color depth, which may or may not be appropriate - it depends on what you plan to use the hbitmap for.

Answer (score 2):

Following sample could help you.

```
BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
BITMAPINFOHEADER &bmInfohdr = (BITMAPINFOHEADER)bmInfo.bmiHeader;

bmInfohdr.biSize = 40 + 255; //I think it's not of use
bmInfohdr.biWidth = x;
bmInfohdr.biHeight = y;
bmInfohdr.biPlanes=1;
bmInfohdr.biBitCount=8;
bmInfohdr.biCompression=0;
bmInfohdr.biSizeImage=0;
bmInfohdr.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmInfohdr.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmInfohdr.biClrUsed = 0;
bmInfohdr.biClrImportant = 0;

           // should I allocate memory further than the 
           // bmColors[1]?? anyway the compiler gives an
           // error for type mismatch!
//bmInfo.bmiColors = (RGBQUAD *) 
                  malloc(sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256);

// here I define the 256 graylevel palette
for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
{
   bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
   bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
   bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = i;
}


BYTE *matrix;
matrix = (BYTE*)malloc(size*sizeof(BYTE));
// here I put the BYTE values of the pixels

CDC *pdcDest = this->GetDC();

HBITMAP hBmp = CreateDIBitmap( pdcDest->m_hDC,
                &bmInfohdr,
                CBM_INIT,
                matrix,    
                &bmInfo,
                DIB_RGB_COLORS);
m_bmpBitmap.Attach( hBmp );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
   int bitmap[WX*WY];  // truecolor bitmap data
   BITMAPINFO bm = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), WX, WY, 1, 32, BI_RGB, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
   HBITMAP bmp = CreateDIBSection( GetDC(win), &bm, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bitmap, 0,0 );
```

(This is specifically configured for 32-bit colors, but you can specify any kind).

Comment: I believe do not have a (practical) window handle at the point in my code where I want to write this. Is there a work-around for the GetDC() part?

Comment: @Kdansky: You can just use the screen DC returned by `GetDC(NULL)`.

Comment: While this doesn't crash or do other evil things, it just results in all my pictures being empty. Are you sure it works when the array contains the complete bitmap, including all headers? I am really storing files in my DB, with all meta data that there is, not just pixel colours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a complete example: http://nishi.dreamhosters.com/u/so_bmp_v0.zip

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

char buf[1<<22];

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  FILE* f = fopen( "winnt.bmp", "rb" ); if( f==0 ) return 1;
  fread( buf, 1,sizeof(buf), f );
  fclose(f);

  BITMAPFILEHEADER& bfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER&)buf[0];
  BITMAPINFO& bi = (BITMAPINFO&)buf[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
  BITMAPINFOHEADER& bih = bi.bmiHeader; 
  char* bitmap = &buf[bfh.bfOffBits];

  int WX=1024, WY=512; // window's width/height
  int SX=bih.biWidth, SY=bih.biHeight;

  HWND win = CreateWindow( "STATIC", "Bitmap test", 0x90C0, 0,0, WX,WY, 0,0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 );

  MSG msg;
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  HDC DC = GetDC(win); // window's DC
  HBITMAP dib = CreateDIBitmap( DC, &bih, CBM_INIT, bitmap, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS );
  HDC dibDC = CreateCompatibleDC( DC ); SelectObject( dibDC, dib );

  ShowWindow( win, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE );
  SetFocus( win );

  while( GetMessage(&msg,win,0,0) ) {
    int m = msg.message;
    if( m==WM_PAINT ) {
      DC = BeginPaint( win, &ps );
      StretchBlt( DC, 0,0,WX,WY, dibDC,0,0,SX,SY, SRCCOPY );
      EndPaint( win, &ps );
    } else if( (m==WM_KEYDOWN) || (m==WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ) {
      break; 
    } else {
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```