# Load image from binary in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Usually I do the image-loading using [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045.aspx) with path or [LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033%28VS.85%29.aspx) with resource ID. But now the target image resource is stored in database(SQLite). So how can I use the binary data *directly*(avoiding store temporary file) retrieved from the db in MFC?

Comment: Check out the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993518/arraybyte-to-hbitmap-or-cbitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found out ,and it works fine in my project.

**1.function for retrieve binary data from sqlite database.**

```
int CSqlite::retrieveBinaryData(int id , byte *pdata)
{
    ASSERT(pdata != NULL);
    int rc,size;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

    sqlite3_prepare(dbh,"select id,content,size from images where id = ?",-1,&stmt,0);

    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt,1,id);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(rc == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        num = sqlite3_column_int(stmt,0);

        size = sqlite3_column_int(stmt,2);
        byte *tmpdata  = (byte * )sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,1);
        memcpy(pdata,tmpdata,size);
        return size;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**2.receive the data from function above and convert it to CBitmap so we can use it.**

```
    byte *tdata = new BYTE[BMP_MAX_SIZE];
    CSqlite *sq = new CSqlite("mysqlite.db");
    int size = sq->retrieveBinaryDatas(myid,tdata);

        /* using the resource mentioned by alfonso in the comment */

    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh;
    bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)tdata;

    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih;
    bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(tdata + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    BITMAPINFO* bmi;
    bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;

    void* bits;
    bits = (void*)(tdata + bmfh->bfOffBits);

    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS) ;

    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    delete tdata;



    BITMAP bitmap; 
    CBitmap   *bmpBackground =  CBitmap::FromHandle(hbmp);
```