# Processing bitmap header

Tags: c, image, bitmap, directx

I have two questions about the [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930979.aspx) structure.

*First*, if we make our own version of that structure the assigned memory would be **16 bytes** because of [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). But that of the [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930979.aspx) is **14 bytes**. why does that happen?

*Second*, as you already know Bitmap Header is Little-Endianed. so when you wish to access the value properly, you need to convert it to the Big-Endian. However if you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993518/arraybyte-to-hbitmap-or-cbitmap), you would see that the accepted answer does nothing. Would you guys explain how can it be possible?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A file can have any type of alignment, and the header of bitmap files happens to be 14 bytes (for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). There is no rule that says that everything must be aligned (exceptions are SSE instructions which expect everything to aligned). Aligned data can be accessed faster, so it is recommended that you align your data, but you don't have to. File formats don't have align their data as well.

You need to convert it to big-endian if you want to read the values, but if you just want to create a new bitmap, you have to store the data in the same format as expected in the BITMAPFILEHEADER struct, which is little-endian.

Comment: Do you mean endianness doesn't matter when you just create a bitmap..? Really?

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit unclear. Endianness is always important, but what I meant is that you need to write data to a file in the same endianness as is specified in the file specification regardless of the endianness of the platform you are running on. For humans it makes sense to read values in big-endian, but if you write big-endian to a BMP file, the file will be incorrect.

Comment: I'm not talking about writing data to a file. I, of course, agree BMP file should be little-endian. But after loading a bmp to byte array, for windows to properly read the values of that structure i guess the endianness of byte array should be considered.

Comment: Yes that it true, you need to take the endianness should be considered when you actually use for example pixel data. But you asked how in the link you provided, the answer does nothing with the endianness. And that is because he calls CreateDIBitmap, which only makes a header. You don't have to worry about the endianness of the values you pass to that method. That's how interpreted your question :)

Comment: I thought CreateDIBitmap cares aboout the endianness. As you can see at the parameters that CreateDIBitmap receives, it is obvious that the function would attempt to access the values of structure BITMAPINFOHEADER, which is without consideration of endianness.

Comment: Would CreateDIBitmap properly read the values of the structure BITMAPINFOHEADER regardless of endianness?

Comment: Ah you're right, I've been looking at the wrong code! *blush* Sorry about that. It is extra complicated because bitmap data also gets stored from bottom to top (and endianness hell). CreateDIBitmap has the lpbmi parameter which points to a BITMAPINFO struct, which contains an array of RGBQUAD structs. RGBQUAD consists of [b,g,r,(reserved)] members, and there you can see the little endianness of the file specification. If you fill in that information then the bitmap will be correctly created of course. I never used that function as I created my own, but that was a long time ago...

Comment: Do you mean, after all, BITMAPFILEHEADER and all other bitmap structures should be stored in little endian?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23915/discussion-between-bis0317-and-oguz-meteer)