# CBitmap from raw RGB values in std::vector<std::uint32_t> holding array

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, mfc

I have a bitmap in raw RGBA values in the following code from a library I found on the net. "svgren.

```
auto img = svgren::render(*dom, width, height); //uses 96 dpi by default
//At this point the 'width' and 'height' variables were filled with
//the actual width and height of the rendered image.
//Returned 'img' is a std::vector<std::uint32_t> holding array of RGBA values.
```

I need to know how to get this picture into a CBitmap so I can display it in an MFC Picture control. I can presize it and I know how to display a bitmap in the control. What I can't do is load the RGBA values into the bitmap. Any ideas please?

Comment: Use createBitmap directly:

Comment: CBitmap Chb;
   HBITMAP bmp = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, &*img.begin());
   ASSERT_ALWAYS(bmp != NULL)
   Chb.Attach(bmp);
   //PicControl.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
   //PicControl.SetBitmap(Chb);
   mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
   mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.SetBitmap(Chb);

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993518/arraybyte-to-hbitmap-or-cbitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CBitmap Chb;
HBITMAP bmp = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, &*img.begin());
ASSERT_ALWAYS(bmp != NULL)
Chb.Attach(bmp);
//PicControl.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
//PicControl.SetBitmap(Chb);
mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.SetBitmap(Chb);
```

Comment: You should be able to use `img.data()` instead of `&*img.begin()` (assuming that's `std::vector`)

Comment: As was established in your [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39596419/1889329), this solution sports both a GDI resource leak and a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The [CBitmap::CreateBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/432f18e2.aspx) member function can construct a bitmap from a block of memory. The *lpBits* argument expects a pointer to **byte** values. Passing a pointer to an array of `uint32_t` values is technically undefined behavior (although it will work on all little-endian implementations of Windows).

Special care must be taken for the memory layout. This is only documented for the Windows API call [CreateBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485.aspx) and not at all present in the MFC documentation:

> Each scan line in the rectangle must be word<sup>1</sup> aligned (scan lines that are not word aligned must be padded with zeros).

Based on the assumption, that the memory is properly aligned, and reinterpreting the buffer as a pointer to bytes is well defined, here's an implementation with proper resource handling:

```
CBitmap Chb;
Chb.CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, img.data());
mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
Chb.Attach(mProjectorWindow.m_picControl.SetBitmap(Chb.Detach()));
```

The last line of code exchanges ownership of the GDI resource between the `m_picControl` and `Chb`. This ensures proper cleanup of the GDI resource previously owned by the `m_picControl`, and makes the `m_picControl` the only owner of the newly created bitmap.

---

<sup>1</sup> *I believe this [should read **dword** aligned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386.aspx).*

Comment: Chm gets the bitmap from CreateBitmap. But then there appears to be no connection between that and SetBitmap? I presume Chm is a member variable CBitmap? Or is it a mis-spelling for Chb?