# C++: How to interpret a byte array representation of an image?

Tags: c++, image, camera

I'm trying to work with this camera SDK, and let's say the camera has this function called CameraGetImageData(BYTE* data), which I assume takes in a byte array, modifies it with the image data, and then returns a status code based on success/failure. The SDK provides no documentation whatsoever (not even code comments) so I'm just guestimating here. Here's a code snippet on what I think works

```
BYTE* data = new BYTE[10000000]; // an array of an arbitrary large size, I'm not 
                                 // sure what the exact size needs to be so I 
                                 // made it large
CameraGetImageData(data);
// Do stuff here to process/output image data
```

I've run the code w/ breakpoints in Visual Studio and can confirm that the CameraGetImageData function does indeed modify the array. Now my question is, is there a standard way for cameras to output data? How should I start using this data and what does each byte represent? The camera captures in 8-bit color.

Comment: Usually it's RGB triples packed into rows and columns.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way for camera to output data. Maybe you should take some special photos (eg. all black, all white, etc.) with this camera and then figure out what's exactly provided in the output data.

Comment: If there is no documentation then you're just going to have to make educated guesses about the format until you find the right one. Start with 24 bit interleaved RGB.

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that the camera is just dumping the raw CCD data, in which case they might not feel the need to repeat the CCD specs.

Answer (score 1):

Take pictures of pure red, pure green and pure blue. See what comes out.

Also, I'd make the array 100 million, not 10 million if you've got the memory, at least initially. A 10 megapixel camera using 24 bits per pixel is going to use 30 million bytes, bigger than your array. If it does something crazy like store 16 bits per colour it could take up to 60 million or 80 million bytes.

You could fill this big array with data before passing it. For example fill it with '01234567' repeated. Then it's really obvious what bytes have been written and what bytes haven't, so you can work out the real size of what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard but you can try to identify which values are what by putting some solid color images in front of the camera. So all pixels would be approximately the same color. Having an idea of what color should be stored in each pixel you may understand how the color is represented in your array. I would go with `black, white, reg, green, blue` images.

But also consider finding a better `SDK` which has the documentation, because making just a big array is really bad design

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation on your camera SDK, since there's no "standard" or "common" way for data output. It can be [raw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) data, it can be RGB data, it can even be already compressed. If the camera vendor doesn't provide any information, you could try to find some libraries that handle most common formats, and try to pass the data you have to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Without even knowing the type of the camera, this question is nearly impossible to answer.
If it is a scientific camera, chances are good that it adhers to the IEEE 1394 (aka IIDC or DCAM) standard. I have personally worked with such a camera made by Hamamatsu using this [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394/) to interface with the camera.

In my case the camera output was just raw data. The camera itself was monochrome and each pixel had a depth-resolution of 12 bit. Therefore, each pixel intensity was stored as 16-bit unsigned value in the result array. The size of the array was simply `width * height * 2` bytes, where `width` and `height` are the image dimensions in pixels the factor `2` is for 16-bit per pixel. The `width` and `height` were known a-priori from the chosen camera mode.

If you have the dimensions of the result image, try to dump your byte array into a file and load the result either in Python or Matlab and just try to visualize the content. Another possibility is to load this raw file with an image editor such as [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) and hope to get anything out from it.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this question's solution will helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340944/291372
Actually you've got an array of pixels (assume 1 byte per pixel if you camera captires in 8-bit). What you need - is just determine width and height. after that you can try to restore bitmap image from you byte array.